Can I replace the WiFi card within my System76 Thelio Mira?
System76 is notorious for having good documentation for repairs/replacements, but alas, I cannot find any details on how to remove the WiFi card.
Does anyone know where the WiFi card on System76's Thelio Mira is hiding?

Usual warnings of "this will completely void your warranty".
From Spiff's answer – he says this has an ASUS board; ASUS tends to package their 'integrated' wireless adaptors in a little shielded assembly right at the back of the system, right back to the PCI days.
In theory you can remove the shroud over the rear IO, unplug the Wi-Fi unit, and replace the Wi-Fi card with another one. There's a video that shows the IO shroud removal process – it's 2 screws and a little careful application of force.
From that video:
The shroud has 2 screws below it circled in grey you need to remove


From this tutorial of a similar unit being disassembled it may be a standard M.2 card in a shell meant to shield it and keep it in place.
Since removal of the Wi-Fi card isn't officially supported, nor documented, System76 probably doesn’t know, or want to take the risk of damaging the motherboard making these changes.

Ah, this clearly a better answer than mine but I'm glad I helped. Go team! ha ha. I'm going to delete my Answer, but just so the relevant info doesn't get lost, I'll add here that the evidence that the System76 Thelio Mira uses an "ASUS ROG Strix X570-E Gaming" motherboard comes from the screening barely visible at the top of the first image in the "Steps to replace the M.2 drives" section of their manual.

Feels like a bit of a waste to delete your answer. There's nothing wrong with it, and outside some fairly obscure knowledge, your answer is mostly right.
